# Counting special characters in SQL

Tags: sql-server

Looking for a SQL query that returns the count of all the special characters used in a particular column. Suppose in a column there are 5 rows and each uses two special characters. I am looking for some query that gives 10 as the result.

I tried to get Special characters rows, but how to get counts of each special characters for all databases in same table ( I have 10 databases in same table and same column )

```
Select * From  tablename Where  Name like '%[^a-z ,-.''0-9]%'
```

Comment: Do you want the number of special characters in all the rows, or the number of rows with special characters in one of the fields?

Comment: Add sample data with expected result

Comment: If Name is  Proof _7' Date  then I need two rows because here we have two special characters. First row Name column and special charcter column is '_' and second row is ' ' ' Single quote

Comment: see the link referenced to know on , how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

So I use a numbers table (virtual created in the CTE) and cross apply with your table taking each character 1 at a time and seeing if it matches your match criteria. I then count the number of rows returned to get the number of special characters:

> SET UP

```
--Create Test Table
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    [Name] VARCHAR(50)
)
-- Insert Sample Data
INSERT INTO #Test
VALUES ('dgas-!gfsdfg'), ('d^0jdn'), (',dfsd%gfs_da')
```

> Query

```
declare @match varchar(50) = '[^a-z ,-.''0-9]'

;WITH Numbers
AS
(
-- Generate Numbers table
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS N
FROM 
    (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) x(n)
CROSS APPLY
    (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) y(n)
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Numbers
CROSS APPLY #Test
WHERE N < DATALENGTH(Name) + 1 -- Only need to get each character
AND  SUBSTRING(Name, N, 1)   LIKE @match -- does it match our expression
```

For my data his returns 4

Comment: In above test data I need out put like this                                                       dgas-!gfsdfg      -                                                                                            2nd row                                                                                                                                                                                    dgas-!gfsdfg      !   like this remaining two rows also

Comment: @Mallikarjuna FIX YOUR QUESTION, don't drag it out in a bunch of comments with code. Add your sample data and desired output there, and delete your comments. Please.